# Images getting parsed after call

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, photoswipe

I'm pulling images into a document via json/ajax. After they get pulled in, I'd like to create a slideshow using the plugin "PhotoSwipe". All of the code is in my document and I can see that the images get pulled but I think it's after PhotoSwipe tries to call them. I get the following error:

Code.PhotoSwipe.createInstance: No images to passed.

Then right after that is all the images that have been logged by my function. Here is my code, if anyone can help, it would be much appreciated!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

          <title></title>

           <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/iphone.css" /> 
          <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/slideshow.css" /> 

          <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 320, user-scalable = no">

              <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
              <script src="scripts/retina.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
              <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/phonegap.js"></script>





            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() { 
                                  $('img').retina(); 
                                  }); 

                $.ajax({
                       url: "http://www.lcbcchurch.com/mobileJSON/homeslideshow",
                       dataType: "json",
                       success:function(data){
                       results(data);
                       }
                       });

                function results(data) {
                    for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
                        // this will log all of the images url
                        console.log(data[i].slideshow_image); // just access the part you want by it's name.
                        $("#slider").append("<a href='"+data[i].slideshow_image+"'></a>");
                    }
picsReady();
                }
                </script>


            <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/klass.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/code.photoswipe-3.0.4.min.js"></script>


                <script type="text/javascript">
               function picsReady() {
                (function(window, Util, PhotoSwipe){
                 Util.Events.domReady(function(e){
                                      var instance;
                                      instance = PhotoSwipe.attach(
                                            window.document.querySelectorAll('#slider a'),
                                            {
                                            target: window.document.querySelectorAll('#PhotoSwipeTarget')[0],
                                            loop: true,
                                            preventHide: true,
                                            autoStartSlideshow: true,
                                            captionAndToolbarHide: true,
                                            margin: 0,
                                            }
                                            );          
                                      instance.show(0);
                                      }, false);
                 }(window, window.Code.Util, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
 }
                </script>


            </head>

      <body>
      <div class="wrapper">


    <img src="img/Welcome.png" width="280" height="57" class="retina welcome" />
    <div id="PhotoSwipeTarget"></div>

              <div id="slider">

              </div>

    <p>
    LCBC is a group of people on a journey with Jesus. We don’t claim to have it all figured   out   and recognize that each of us is in a different spot on that journey. From those just     exploring Jesus, to those starting to figure out how to walk with Him, to those fully engaged     in that pursuit— everyone is welcome here!

    </p>    
    </div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to check how things are getting fired... from what it looks like your images are loading on an on ready function, but so is the swipe, so the swipe function doesn't know there are images there since technically its being called at the same time as the images.

try adding a function that calls the swipe to initiate after your photos have been loaded...

Comment: Hey Drew - Thanks for answering my question again. I tried adding a function call right after the close of "function results(data)". Then I put the function around my entire second chunk of script. This is the way I added the call: "picsReady();" & the function "function picsReady() { script };". Am I doing something wrong? It seems like my second chunk of script doesn't even get called. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: try adding the picsReady() function after the for loop, so it's still in the results function... give that a shot and see if that works!

Comment: I updated my code above to show you what I'm doing. Still not working for some reason. Not getting any errors. The console show that the images are getting pulled, but the slideshow doesn't show the images. I still think the images are getting pulled after the slideshow plugin.

Comment: it looks like there is a DOM loaded that is the problem. Even though the function is being called the slideshow has that loader... what if you put that at the bottom of the page? It's different in phonegap since the DOM really doesn't load other than the ondevice ready... question have you looked at iscroll? There is a really nifty snap scroll which would work well for swiping image left - right up and down...

Comment: Hey Drew, as always, thanks for the comments. I got it up and running. What I did was just switch out "Util.Events.domReady(function(e){" for "$(document).ready(function(e){". Now everything is working incredibly smoothly. Thanks for the comments though, the function is doing the trick now. I'll let you know when I hit my next road block ;)

Comment: awesome! :) it's always something random. glad I was able to steer you in the right direction.